# magento 2.2.3 HOW CAN I DO THIS SITUATION? When referee signs up, referrer receives 200points, referee receives 100 points

Tags: reward-points, referral

> **Magento 2.2.3** **HOW CAN I DO THIS SITUATION**? *When referee signs up, referrer receives 200points, referee receives 100 points .*

Answer (score 0):

You can below Extension for refer-a-friend programs:
https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/refer-a-friend.html#magento2